# Xcode 8: Custom font doesn't work on simulator and phone, but in IB it is works

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts, interface-builder

Xcode 8, iOS 10

Custom font Calibri.ttf:

- added to Resources
- added to Targets/Build Phases/Copy Bundle Resources
- font added to plist
- Label font is Calibri in IB

Simulator and phone display NOT custom font

Comment: Do you load your font from IB when you run on simulator or programmatically?

Comment: font loads from IB

Comment: If I load font programmatically - then it's works

Comment: Are you dealing with attributed text or something?